# Python ttk grid does not show all elements

Tags: python, grid, tkinter, ttk

I'm trying to make a simplified calendar widget in Tkinter/ttk to allow me to select month and year. I fail to get all of my elements to show. In the form given below, it only shows the combobox with the months. I'm sure, I'm just making some stupid error that someone else will point out instantly, and I will then proceed to facepalm at my stupidity :-). The goal is to have the buttons, the entry and the combobox all show in the configuration:

```
| <Button | Entry | >Button |
|          Combobox         |
|        ChooseButton       |
```

If I uncomment self.pack(), it hangs. If I uncomment self.pack() AND comment away self.box.grid, it shows the rest of the widgets. Now, I assume I'm not supposed to used pack and grid together, I just tried it because I saw other people do it and I figured I might just as well give it a try.

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from ttk import Frame, Combobox, Button, Entry
import calendar, re

def printThisFunc(string):
    def printFunc():
        print string
    return printFunc

class SelectMonthDialog(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, startDate):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, padding='10px')   
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title('Select month')
        button = Button(self, text='<', command = printThisFunc('<'))
        button.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.yearEntry = Entry(self)
        self.yearEntry.insert(0,str(startDate.year))
        self.yearEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        button = Button(self, text='>', command = printThisFunc('>'))
        button.grid(row=0, column=2)
        months = calendar.month_name[1:]
        self.box = Combobox(self.parent, state='readonly')
        self.box['values'] = months
        self.box.current(startDate.month-1)
        self.box.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3)
        button = Button(self, text='Choose', command = printThisFunc('choose'))
        button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3)
        #self.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from datetime import datetime
    root = Tk()
    SelectMonthDialog(root, datetime.today())
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the widgets you create have a parent of `self`. That means they are children of the widget that is an instance of `SelectMonthDialog`. However, you don't ever pack/place/grid that frame in its parent, so it and all of its children remain invisible.

The reason the combobox shows up is because its parent is the parent widget.

The solution is to:

1. make the parent of the combobox be `self` so it becomes part of the `SelectMonthDialog` frame
2. pack `self` in its parent so that it is visible

Answer (score 0):

For some elements you set `self` as `parent` for others you set `self.parent` as `parent` - use only one of them.

If you use `self.parent` you put elements inside `root` and you don't need `self` (`Frame`). Using `self.pack()` you probably replace all elements in `root` with `Frame`.

If you use `self` you put elements inside `Frame` and you have to put `Frame` inside `root` so you need `self.pack()`

Comment: Thanks to you as well for th explanation. I had to pick one as the correct answer, Bryan just happened to be first :-).